# WooCommerce: how to set stock per attribute on variable product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, customization

So I have a variable product with the attributes "time" and "package".

Time has 3 options: "1 week", "2 weeks", "3 weeks"

Package has 2: "Full ticket" and "half ticket"

This creates 6 variations.

My question is:
Is there a way to set stock levels per attribute rather than per "variations".

Currently, I can only set stock for the parent or per **variation**, but I need to set a stock for the **attribute** "package".

Full ticket has 80 stock count and "half ticket" has 50.

The weeks don't matter.

Either a stock count per attribute or the ability to create multiple stock counts per product and assign which stock to decrease in each variation.

Any ideas?

Comment: so you could simply remove the option `used for variations` on the time attribute..?

Comment: The time variation is crucial as it allows me to setup recurring re-payments, so I am just looking to assign a stock count to the package attributes.

Comment: ok then. so i would still leave out the time variation (you dont even need that attribute at all) and code that variation in there via filter. you could add a custom taxonomy to the products with that behavior so you could individually add this filter..